# S-Corp owner salary change between pay periods

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company, s-corporation, payroll-taxes, payroll

I searched a lot, but couldn't find any concrete answer for this question:

When LLC S-Corp (Myself & Spouse), owners need to get paid "reasonable salary". I am planning to to run the payroll "quarterly", the problem is, we may not have consistent income (due to projects).

Now the question is, are we allowed to adjust (increase/decrease) our salary for the pay period based on income? We are thinking of keeping 60% of income for that quarter as payroll consistently.

Appreciate any input, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're allowed. In fact, it happens quite frequently to employees who work on hourly basis (shift-based employees, temporary workers, etc).

As long as you set a reasonable hourly rate and consistently stick to the same way of evaluating the work scope and tracking the time spent, you should be OK.

That said, if *all* your S-Corp income is due to your own work, I find it hard to explain the 60% salary out of it. Generally S-Corp makes sense if you're generating income in ways that are not only by your own work (through your employees for example).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! myself and spouse together expecting 300k+ (LLC + W2) for this year and we have ZERO savings. So, we would like to use S-Corp approach to put more into solo 401k etc.,. Having 60% salary approach helps in hitting the 60K max IRA savings. Hope this make sense.

Comment: @kosa max 401k savings you mean? You'll probably want to talk to a licensed tax adviser (i.e.: EA/CPA licensed in your state). But yes, it does make sense, at least in terms of understanding of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: https://wcginc.com/business-services/s-corp-salary/ This article discusses some ways to set your salary, including examples below 60%. An hourly rate (to facilitate estimating a part-time salary) could be estimated using Salary.com.

Comment: Be careful relying on various articles touting numbers based on statistics. Facts and circumstances do matter, so you cannot just come up with random numbers because some site said that's what the average is based on some statistics.

Comment: @littleadv thanks for the input. Yes, I am reaching out to CPA (but having this information helps me in discussing with CPA, which is why asking here). I understand all of this information need to be carefully picked based on situations.  Appreciate all the inputs from community.